# How to convert dd/MM/yyyy string to MM-dd-YYYY DateTime int C#

Tags: c#, string, date, date-parsing

What is the best way to convert string (dd/MM/yyyy) to date (MM-dd-YYYY) in C#?

```
string date = "15/01/2017";
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(date, new CultureInfo("en-CA"));
btnBack.Text = date1.ToString();
```

I have error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use explicit formats in your case, you can do that by using `ParseExact` to get the `DateTime` object and then providing the desired format to the `ToString` overload:

```
string date = "15/01/2017";
DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
btnBack.Text = date1.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```